# How to resize nav-pill on collapse using bootstrap 5?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I am essentially trying to create active classes with Bootstrap to display a nav-pill/container around the active section of my webpage. This works fine on larger screens, but on smaller screens, with the hamburger menu active the nav-pill stretches across the entire div/container, but I want it to wrap around only the word similar to when it is a large screen.

Here is a codepen with some filler content to mimic my issue: https://codepen.io/100emoji/pen/mdxdpzp

and the code for the navbar only:

```html
<!-- Bootstrap-5 -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<!-- Body -->
<body data-bs-spy="scroll" data-bs-target="#navbar" data-bs-offset="400" data-bs-smooth-scroll="true">
  <!-- Navigation Bar-->
  <nav id="navbar" class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-dark navbar-dark py-3 sticky-top">
    <div class="container">
      <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Ken's Art & Frame</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler collapsed d-flex d-md-none flex-column justify-content-around" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navmenu">
            <span class="toggler-icon top-bar"></span>
            <span class="toggler-icon mid-bar"></span>
            <span class="toggler-icon bot-bar"></span>
            </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navmenu">
        <ul class="navbar-nav nav-pills ms-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#about" class="nav-link anchor">About Us</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#services" class="nav-link anchor">Services</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#art" class="nav-link anchor">Artwork</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#contact" class="nav-link anchor">Contact Us</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

I can only find solutions using bootstrap 4 through google

Answer (score 0):

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/navbar/#containers

I think this is what you are looking for. Essentially you wrap a container around your UL to control the size.

The other option is to use the bootstrap width classes on each individual <li> like this:

```
<li class="nav-item w-50">
```

Or do it via CSS on <li> tags:

```
li {
    width: 30%;
}
```